# How to get the validation in rules() method?

Tags: php, yii

Just for explanation,here is the table

```
create table test(mark int,item1 varchar(128),item2 varchar(128));
```

If mark==1 then item1 requires a value ,if mark==2 then item2 requires a value

In rules() method,how can I get this rule?

Comment: Are you using a framework like Kohana or Wordpress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your custom validating function in the model, smth. like this:

```
public function requiredMark($attributes,$params)
{
    if ($this->mark == 1 && $this->item1==null)
        $this->addError('item1','Item 1 is required');
    elseif ($this->mark == 2 && $this->item2==null)
        $this->addError('item2','Item 2 is required');
}
```

Or u was asking about something other?

Comment: This is one way to go. I answered a similar question in little more detail here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10584858/creating-rules-for-a-code-field-if-that-field-is-not-disabled-in-yii/10589315#10589315

Comment: hm, dont know if scenario could be implemented here, because we dont know value of the 'mark' field, before the post data will come(when creating a new record). On Edit, yes we can use 'scenario' because we know value of the 'mark'(from database). Anyway i think it's better to have on rule (custom function), that use multiply scenarios (in this example), but your example "has the right to be" )

Comment: Sorry but I am a newer to Yii,that's what I want.Thanks for your answer! And there is another question, which attribute should I use when I get   this validation method into rules's array?I've tried,only use item1,it will work,but is it appropriate?

Comment: smth. like this:`array('mark','requiredMark')` and ofcourse u must have item1 and item2 in your model. Please read in the guide about validation and models too http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/form.model

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to extend the validate() method to do this, and add errors manually. I always get back to this document for validator options (it might be useful later on)

http://yii.googlecode.com/files/yii-1.1.0-validator-cheatsheet.pdf