# Yii compare password only working for one field

Tags: php, validation, yii

I'm using Yii's built in compare validator to compare two form attributes:

```
<div class="row ">
<?php echo $form->labelEx($model, 'newPassword', array('class'=>'control-label'));?>
<?php echo $form->passwordField($model, 'newPassword',array('class'=>'span5','maxlength'=>100)); ?>
<?php echo $form->error($model, 'newPassword'); ?>
</div>
<div class="row">
<?php echo $form->labelEx($model, 'confirmPassword', array('class'=>'control-label'));?>
<?php echo $form->passwordField($model, 'confirmPassword',array('class'=>'span5','maxlength'=>100)); ?>
<?php echo $form->error($model, 'confirmPassword'); ?>
</div>
```

With the rules:

```
array('newPassword', 'length', 'max'=>100,'min'=>6),
array('newPassword', 'compare', 'compareAttribute'=>'username','operator'=>'!=', 'message'=>'Password must not be the same as username'),
array('newPassword', 'compare', 'compareAttribute'=>'confirmPassword','message'=>'Please enter the same password twice'),
array('confirmPassword', 'safe'),
```

When I first type the newPassword, the validation fires and the "enter the same" error message shows. If I then enter the confirmPassword correctly, it doesn't hide. If I then change the confirmPassword, and then change the newPassword to match., the error hides. It only seems to work when I change the newPassword field - so I have to fill in the form backwards for it to hide the error correctly.

Am I missing something?

[edit] I can force the validation to trigger on the field that has the compareAttribute rule, by using JavaScript to temporarily empty the field's value, triggering the validation, then reapplying the previous value and triggering validation again. Seems a little nuts though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you're using client-side validation?

I believe the reason for this not working as you desire is that the rules for newPassword aren't triggered when you change a field besides the newPassword field.

Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to trigger validation on one field when you've changed another, though it looks like you asked [that question before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11469194/trigger-yii-field-validation-onchange-of-another-field).  Jon's answer there seems to suggest you could use [`$.fn.yiiactiveform.updateInput`](http://code.google.com/p/yii/source/browse/tags/1.1.10/framework/web/js/source/jquery.yiiactiveform.js#239) in an onchange in javascript to trigger the validation?

Comment: Thanks - I didn't really want to have to write a custom validator when one already exists to do the job. In the previous question I'd already worked around it (and accepted the answer) by the same the mention of updateInput was added. I couldn't see how to find the attribute object so I didn't pursue it further. In the afterValidateAttribute method, the attribute object given is the one that's triggered, so there's still no attribute object for the other form field (without dumbly hardcoding all the parameters and hoping nothing changes in the model) - so that still won't work in this case.

Comment: [This question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10584858/creating-rules-for-a-code-field-if-that-field-is-not-disabled-in-yii) seems to detail how to do this.  It does seem that you need to use a numeric index, rather than a named index to access the attribute, so if the model changes, things could break.  Maybe blindly check all the fields if only a few have validation?

Comment: Thanks Ernie - not really sure how that relates to my question though - I want to trigger the client side validation *all the time* when either field is changed. It's looking like my ugly hack is the way to go - I was hoping that I was misunderstanding something, and not that the compare validator needed hacking to work properly.

Comment: @Hippyjim In the accepted answer for that question, there's a code block denoted with "If you want instant, ajax feedback, when the user changes the dropdown, you might want this in your view:"  That code block shows how to trigger validation on a second field (in that case changing the dropdown triggers a text); in yours you'd want password1 to trigger password2, and vice-versa

Comment: wow thanks - I totally missed that in that answer. that's exactly what I needed.

Answer (score -2):

Set the operator

```
array('newPassword', 'compare', 'compareAttribute'=>'confirmPassword','operator'=>'==' ,'message'=>'Please enter the same password twice'),**strong text**
```